# How to produce Parallel Trends table and graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel-data, plm, economics

I have been performing panel estimations with municipality fixed effects. I would like to produce robustness checks to verify my results. One of the these is the proof of parallel trends. How can I do this with R?

Say I perform 3 regressions for 3 dependent variables (Y) such:

```
Reg1 <- plm(Y1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + factor(state_year), 
              index = c("city"),
              data = final_panel, model ="within")

Reg2 <- plm(Y2 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + factor(state_year), 
              index = c("city"),
              data = final_panel, model ="within")

Reg3 <- plm(Y3 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + factor(state_year), 
              index = c("city"),
              data = final_panel, model ="within")
```

First, I would like to output the results of this regression by year in a table, with the columns corresponding to the 3 dependent variables and the rows corresponding to the years analyzed, with coefficients and standard deviations. Like such:

```
| Years |     Y1    |    Y2     |    Y3     |
| ----- | --------- | --------- | --------- |
| - 2   | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) |
| - 1   | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) |
|   0   | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) |
|   1   | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) |
|   2   | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) | Coef (sd) |
```

Finally, I would like to plot these results to a line graph using ggplot. I think geom_line() + geom_errorbar() might be the way to go.

I would appreciate any help. I'm quite new to R and econometrics so please forgive any errors in the explanation. Thank you so much.